# How do I get rid of the TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a web scraper and the weird thing is, sometimes the code works and sometimes it doesn't, without changing anything, it might be the websites problem but how could I fix it so it would work at all times?

I've tried rebuilding line 31 multiple times, yet it doesn't seem to work no matter how I do it.

```py
# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs each appartment
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"list-item-container"})

filename = "asunnot.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "Kohdetta Vuokraa, Huoneistot, Talotyyppi ja Koko, Sijainti, Vapautuu, Vuokra"

f.write(headers)
count = 0
for page in range(1,10):
    my_url = "https://www.vuokraovi.com/vuokra-asunnot/Uusimaa?page={}&pageType="
    for container in containers:

        Vuokranantaja = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-4"})[0].img["alt"]

        Huoneistot = container.findAll("li", {"class":"semi-bold"})[1].text

        Talotyyppi = container.findAll("li", {"class":"semi-bold"})[0].text

        Sijainti = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-3"})[0].findAll("span", {"class":"address"})[0].text.strip().replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",", ", ")

        Vapautuu = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-3"})[0].findAll("span", {"class":"showing-lease-container hidden-xs"})[0].li.text

        Vuokra = container.findAll("li", {"class":"rent"})[0].text.strip()
```

Desired output would be to give me the stuff I am trying to scrape, but instead it's giving me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\----\Desktop\vuokraovi.py", line 31, in <module>
    Vuokranantaja = container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-4"})[0].img["alt"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `container.findAll("div", {"class":"hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-4"})[0].img["alt"]` is returning None. So asking for element [0] of nothing is what gives that error. Also, the line in your loop `my_url = "https://www.vuokraovi.com/vuokra-asunnot/Uusimaa?page={}&pageType="` gets stored, but is never used for anything

Comment: you could tell us what the expected return values are as well e.g. price, address...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get, `'NoneType' is not subscriptable`, means you're trying to access something by index on `None`, i.e. something like `None[idx]`.

So, before trying to access item `[0]` on a `container.findAll()` result, you should first check whether there is something or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just sometimes there is nothing to scrape with findAll method. Check exception handling in documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions